# How to run CAS Server and client simultaneously

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm studying **Spring Security 3.1** book by *Robert Winch*. In the book there is example code for CAS Server and corresponding Client application as two separate projects. Please explain me how to run both applications simultaneously. Here is the [Github link](https://github.com/rajdeokumarsingh/spring_security)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the deploy in the same server. The important is your client do SSO and others operations in your CAS Server even if the client and CAS Server stay in the same server.